# How do I make Google Compute Engine based domain private use only?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've been using a compute-engine to host a website on gcloud. I just can't figure out how to make access to the project private, with a whitelist for pre-approved emails.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the answer based on comment.

You can use IAP ( Identity Aware Proxy) to control who can or cannot access your public website [1](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/authenticating-web-users#configure). [Enabling IAP for GCP VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-compute-howto)

Comment: Hi, so essentially the website is currently viewable to the public. I've got a generic VM made with a wordpress website, and I'd like to restrict access so that only people who have a role that i've created for their email can access it

Comment: Edited the answer based on your comment

Comment: @MoudyHasan WordPress supports user authentication. Require uses to login. There are numerous plugins enhancing authentication: https://auth0.com/wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Developing the above answer:

The Identity-Aware Proxy will allow you to Use identity and context to guard access to your applications and VMs.

Your use case would be [setting up IAP for Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/tutorial-gce), which has a few [requirements](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-compute-howto#before_you_begin), like having a HTTPS load balancer .

If you just want to allow specific users to access your website there are some alternatives:

- Install a plugin to restrict access, for example [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restricted-site-access/).
- Restrict GCP Instance's traffic access through [Firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls). This is not recommended because you will need fixed IP addresses for the users, or they should use a VPN to always connect from same fixed IP address.
- You could whitelist IP's from the web server side program, for example for [Apache whitelist](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) or [Nginx whitelist](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-app-protect/configuration/#deny-and-allow-lists)

By doing this the website will still be publicly available but only allowed users could access the website and modify it or access private content of the website.